# Capture variable with zero or one slashes in Django URL

Tags: regex, python-2.7, django-urls

I need to match a Django URL pattern that can contain zero or one slashes. So far I've got a pattern that matches any number of characters, including slashes.

```
url(r'^(?P<myvar>[\w/-]+)/', index.home)
```

I tried adding a question mark after the slash in the variable pattern, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
url(r'^(?P<myvar>[\w/?-]+)/', index.home)
```

To be absolutely clear, I want to capture strings such as `foo` and `foo/bar` but not `foo/bar/bing`.

**EDIT:**

So my root URL is example.com. I need three different routes: one for the main page, one for variable foo that can either be just an alphanumerical string or an alphanumerical string containing one slash, and one for two variables foo and bar where bar must be a simple alphanumerical string.

```
example.com            # should lead to main page
example.com/hey        # should lead to second route where foo="hey"
example.com/hey/ho     # should lead to second route where foo="hey/ho"
example.com/hey/ho/hi  # should lead to third route where foo="hey/ho" and bar="hi"
```

So I need to capture `foo` and `bar` as variables, where foo can either contain a slash or not contain a slash. *But as far as this question is concerned*, I'm only interested in capturing `foo`.

Comment: Example would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to capture specific parts in an URL.

```
^[^/]*\/(?P<foo>(?:[^/\n]*(?:/[^/\n]*)?))(?:/(?P<bar>.*))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/7)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not match `foo`. I removed everything but `foo` in your demo and didn't get any matches.

Comment: please post an example and explain what do you want to capture.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I will examine it closer. I've also expanded my question.

Comment: That looks more like what I'm after. Thank you!